# Angles inside a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> $P$ is a point inside triangle $ABC$ such that $\angle ABP=20^{\circ} $  , $\angle PBC=10^{\circ}$,
>   $∠ ACP = 20°$ and  $∠ PCB = 30°$. Determine $∠CAP$ , in degree.

No figure was given

I used the sine Law but the could not solve equations I got, I also tried making a point $D$ on $BP$ such that $BD = CD$ to make us of the $10^{\circ}$, but I still cant solve it.

Comment: "No figure was given"  Then draw one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
The angle measure can be found by solving the 3 separate equations obtained by using the sine rule on $\triangle$s ABP, APC  &  PBC .

Using sine rule on △ ABP , we get

$$\frac{AP}{BP}= \frac{\sin 20}{\sin  (100-x)}$$

Using sine rule on △s APC & BPC , and eliminating PC from the equations , we get

$$\frac{AP}{BP}= \frac{\sin 10 * \sin 20 }{\sin x * \sin 30} $$

From the two equations , we get $$\frac{\sin x}{2}= \sin (100-x)*\sin 10$$

Rewriting $ \sin (100-x)$ as $\cos (10-x)$ , and using the cosine sum formula, we get

$$\cot x = \frac{1-2\sin^2(10)}{2\sin10*\cos10} $$

Since  $1 - 2\sin^2(t) = \cos 2t $ and $ 2\sin t * \cos t = \sin 2t $, we get

$$\cot x = \cot 20 $$
which implies $x$ is $\boxed{20°}$

Answer (score 0):

Extend BP so that it intersects AC at D and extend CP so that it intersects AB at E. Now consider triangle ADP and triangle AEP these triangle are congruent so angle APD =70 and angle DEC=40 APD+DEC=APC=110 Hence angle CAP=30

Comment: How do we know that triangles ADP and AEP congruent?

Answer (score 0):

Rotate $P$ for $-60^{\circ}$ around $B$ to new point $D$. Then $D$ is a center of a circumcircle for triangle $BCP$ so $$\angle CDP = 2\angle CBP = 20^{\circ}$$

So $ABCD$ is cyclic since $$\angle CDB +\angle CAB = 180^{\circ}$$

$ABCD$ is also a trapez since $$\angle CBP = \angle ACB = 50^{\circ}$$

So $AB = DC = BP$ and thus  $\angle BAP = \angle BPA = 80^{\circ}$ and there for  $$\angle CAP = 20^{\circ}$$

[image]